# how to add a new controller method ruby on rails without a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, view, controller

I want to add a new method in the controller, so i can send an ajax request from the js, without changing the view.

I have add the following in the controller:

```
  def select_teams
@team = Team.where(@team.champeonship_id >= params[:champeonship_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @team.save
    format.json { render :text => @team }
  else
    format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

and the following in routes.rb

```
resources :teams do
collection do
  post :select_teams
end
```

end

The problem is that when i make the request the controller call set_team with id=select_teams

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem in a bit of more detail?

Comment: I just wanna make an ajax request to a function in the controller that returns me the results of a "Select". I have searched how to do it, so i added a method en the controller and the route but didn't work because intead of calling the method i created calls set_team.

Comment: Can you post the js file where your triggering the ajax request

Comment: function select_teams(){
  $.ajax({
        url:    "/teams/select_teams",
        type:   "POST",
        data:   {champeonship_id: 1},
        success: function(response){
            alert('hola');
        }
      });
}

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that set_teams is being called in the wrong places

At the top of the controller there should be something like

```
before_action :set_teams, except: [:index, :new, :select_teams]
```

You might just need to add the select teams to it.